# Should these 2 questions be merged?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Should these 2 questions be merged?

[Is there an official Marvel Cinematic Universe viewing order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/is-there-an-official-marvel-films-viewing-order)

[Which films should I see before "The Avengers"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16080/which-films-should-i-see-before-the-avengers/34122#34122)

Comment: Also, related is this (but very precise so not a dupe. IMHO) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34975/should-i-watch-the-avengers-before-going-to-see-iron-man-3/35033#35033

Comment: well since (I learned that) dupes are determined by dupe answers, I'm not so sure it's not a dupe.

Comment: Doesn't merging effectively delete one of the questions? We can merge *or* mark as dupe, right?

Comment: @phantom42 - correct. I am indifferent to which of the 2 routes are taken, but feel that one of them should.

Answer (score 1):

I think neither merging nor closing should happen.  There are 3 questions:

1. I am watching all of the Phase 1 Marvel movies, what order should I watch them in?
2. I am watching *Avengers*, which Phase 1 Marvel movies should be watched first?
3. (from your comment) I am watching a Phase 2 Marvel movie (i.e. *Iron Man 3*), which non-*Iron Man* Phase 1 Marvel movies should be watched first.

That someone can answer all of these questions with 'watch all of Phase 1' doesn't make them equivalent, especially since the justification for **why** you'd answer with 'watch all of Phase 1' will wildly vary with each question.  In addition, listing all of Phase 1 in a specific order has a specific meaning in the [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) questions, which isn't necessarily present in the non-[suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) question.